# How can I parse this table to datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datagridview, html-agility-pack

I found an example of code parsing web table to a csv and write data to a text file in computer but I want to parse it instead of computer location to my `datagridview`.

> I dont understand why cant i add this question as it says: It looks
>   like your post is mostly code; please add some more details; it is not good Stuckoverflow! I dont need to much speaky ricky I just have few words and code example thats what this site should be about and not pop up warning to 'write more man' LOL.

Here is html website:

```
            <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                        <td>Singapore</td>
                        <td>28</td>
                        <td>2010/11/14</td>
                        <td>$357,650</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>28</td>
                        <td>2011/06/07</td>
                        <td>$206,850</td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>37</td>
                        <td>2009/08/19</td>
                        <td>$139,575</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Donna Snider</td>
                        <td>Customer Support</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>2011/01/25</td>
                        <td>$112,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

and here is code which needs to be modified:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Class1

    Public Function Demo1() As DataTable
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim Document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://website.com/table.html"), HttpWebRequest)
        myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compat ble; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
        Dim streamRead = New StreamReader(CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
        Dim res As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Document.Load(res.GetResponseStream, True)

        Dim table As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='example']")

        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        If table IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim rows = table.SelectNodes("tr")
            If rows Is Nothing AndAlso table.SelectSingleNode("tbody") IsNot Nothing Then
                rows = table.SelectSingleNode("tbody").SelectNodes("tr")
            End If

            For row As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1
                'if row = then these are headers
                If row = 0 Then
                    Dim cols = rows(row).SelectNodes("th")
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(0).InnerText.ToString()))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(1).InnerText.ToString()))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(2).InnerText.ToString()))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(3).InnerText.ToString()))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(4).InnerText.ToString()))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(5).InnerText.ToString()))
                Else
                    Dim cols = rows(row).SelectNodes("td")
                    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                    dr(0) = cols(0).InnerText.ToString()
                    dr(1) = cols(1).InnerText.ToString()
                    dr(2) = cols(2).InnerText.ToString()
                    dr(3) = cols(3).InnerText.ToString()
                    dr(4) = cols(4).InnerText.ToString()
                    dr(5) = cols(5).InnerText.ToString()
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                End If
            Next

        End If
        Return dt

    End Function

End Class
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The reason for the warning that your post is mostly code is that you need to explain your problem. I'm afraid that simply posting code and asking for someone to fix it is not on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

First select the closest thing you need, that could be table or could be something even closer to data. Since I can't see the exact html I used the html you provided as an example (one of the ways to do it).

What I basically did is navigate to rows of data, then looped over them while for each column of given row I grabbed data and then put it into DGV.

I made the DGV headers beforehand in designer. (ou can do it programmatically but if it's a fixed/single website then you can do it manually)

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim WebDoc As New HtmlDocument
        WebDoc.LoadHtml(TextBox1.Text) 'Your url appears to be blank so icopied the html

        Dim RowNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = WebDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr")
        For Each _HTMLNode As HtmlNode In RowNodes
            'There's multple ways to do the column thing
            Dim ColumnCollection As String = Nothing
            For Each _SubNode As HtmlNode In _HTMLNode.SelectNodes("./td") 'Columns there apepar to be some #text nodes we dont need, probably cuzz i used textbox
                ColumnCollection &= "✄" & _SubNode.InnerText 'some non standard symbol used for spliting string later
            Next
            ColumnCollection = ColumnCollection.Substring(1) 'remove first symbol
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(ColumnCollection.Split({"✄"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Keep in mind that all the data is treated as string. You need additional code for setting it to proper data type if you need it.

Comment: ok cool I will go to try now; just one more question please: why you said 'additional code for setting it to proper data type' if this works why we do need it?

Comment: ok I tested but I'm getting same error over and over like the previous project 'System.NullReferenceException: bject reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: And did you fix it yet? I guess that's because you don't have a textbox. You have to adapt the code and put response stream instead of textbox.

Comment: I removed textbox of course and added my url but it doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough, what kind of error you are getting and where?

Comment: Finally I make it work BUT the first column of data populate normal; but the rest is underline and looks blue like url link; do you know why?